# What's wrong with my foreach loop?

Tags: .net, powershell, scripting, command

I wrote this foreach loop to add all users to the local administrator group save for a few conditions. It seems to go through the first two if statements fine, but I get the error "The group already exists" when it comes to the portion that adds users to the admin group. Any Ideas?

```
$UserList = Net User

foreach ($User in $UserList)
{
    if($User -match "Lcs")
    {
        Write-Host "FCS Account Excluded."
    }

    if($User -match "Guest" -Or $User -match "Administrator")
    {
        Write-Host "Default Windows Accounts Excluded."
    }
    else 
    {
        net localgroup Administrators $User /Add
    }
}
```

Comment: First line in the output from `net user` is an empty string, so you end up calling `net localgroup Administrators  /Add` - the command for *creating* a group called `Administrators`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  Ahh, so how do I select the users in the output from `net user` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way of `Net User` stores the users.

Try the following block:

```
$UserList = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount  -Filter "LocalAccount='True'"
foreach ($User in $UserList)
{
    if($User.Name -match "Lcs")
    {
        Write-Host "FCS Account Excluded."
    }
    elseif ($User.Name -match "Guest" -Or $User.Name -match "Administrator")
    {
        Write-Host "Default Windows Accounts Excluded."
    }
    else 
    {
        net localgroup Administrators $User.Name /Add
    }
}
```

Also I don't recommend to use the `Net local group administrators user.add` since it is using another app net, but no problem on using it.

Comment: I get the following error before the second line when running your block : `Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select LocalAccount='True' from Win32_UserAccount-Filter"
At line:1 char:13
+ $UserList = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount-Filter  "LocalAccount='True'"
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand`

Comment: Sorry I missed a space between the Win32_UserAccount and - Filter. Edited now.

Answer (score 1):

The output from the `net user` command looks like this:

```
PS C:\> net user

User accounts for \\ComputerName

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user01               user02               user03               user04
user05               user06
The command completed successfully

PS C:\>
```

Notice that the first 4 lines are useless if you're just interested in the usernames, as are the two last lines. You can remove them with `Select-Object -Skip` and `Select-Object -First`:

```
PS C:\> $netuser = net user |Select-Object -Skip 4
PS C:\> $netuser |Select-Object -First $($netuser.Length - 3)
user01               user02               user03               user04
user05               user06
PS C:\>
```

Now you just need to split the usernames into individual strings:

```
PS C:\> $users = $netuser |Select-Object -First $($netuser.Length - 3) |ForEach-Object {
    $_.Split(' ',[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
}
PS C:\> $users
user01
user02
user03
user04
user05
user06
```

Comment: Would this work on multiple machines? For example, say if there were more users, so there ended up being 3 rows of usernames instead of 2.